# Unable to install Anaconda on my Windows 11 64-bit PC

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, anaconda, pythonpath

I am getting the following error while installing anaconda on my Windows 11 machine.

I have already tried the below steps, but it still doesnt seem to work:

1. Uninstall any previous Anaconda or Python installations.
2. Download the latest, 64-bit Anaconda version from its official site.
3. Temporarily disable antivirus software.
4. If the system path environment variable is too long (>260 characters), shorten it.
5. Run the installer as an administrator.
6. Make sure disk has sufficient space for the installation.

Are there some pre-requisities for installing anaconda? Some librarires or files that probably I might have inadvertently deleted from my system or the path variable which I might have messed around in the past, that is now impacting my installation process?

Just to let you know, my system is:

1. 16 GB RAM,
2. Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.59 GHz
3. 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this approach

uninstall Anaconda if you have installed it previously and remove any related folders `e.g., C:\Users\xxx\anaconda3`

Download the latest version of Anaconda.

Install it to a short path without spaces, `e.g.,  C:\Anaconda3`

Adjust Environment Variables: Search `Environment Variables` on your PC. Edit the `Path` variable in `System Variables`. Add `C:\Anaconda3` & `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts`

Restart your system and open CMD as administrator and type `conda --version`

---

> ## I am posting step-by-step also

[image]

Click the ‘Next >’ button to proceed.

[image]

Click on the `I Agree` button to agree to the terms

[image]

click on the ‘Next >’ button to proceed.

[image]

Click on the ‘Next >’ button to continue

[image]

now leave the section as it is
and click on install button

than

Click the ‘Next >’ button to proceed.
[image]

[image]

### Configuration Anaconda3

> Upgrade Anaconda Navigator

upgrade Anaconda Navigator using these steps:

1. Click on the ‘Yes’ button
2. Windows will ask for permission to allow the application to make
   changes to your device.
3. then Click on the Yes button to continue
   Continue the procedure

for more information you also follow https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/windows/